# Spring MVC No mapping found for HTTP request with URI /x/ in DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring-mvc

I've seen this post with no solutions.  I'm trying to run a Spring MVC tutorial but for some reason I'm not able to get the mapping in my servlet to call my home.jsp found in /WEB-INF/jsps directory.  My context root is set to spring in Eclipse Web Project Settings.  The error I'm getting is:

```
    INFO    2016-11-06 11:18:59,613 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] 
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - 
      FrameworkServlet 'offers': initialization completed in 486 ms
    WARN    2016-11-06 11:18:59,623 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] 
     org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  
     - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/spring/] 
     in DispatcherServlet with name 'offers'
```

My code is as follows:

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
             xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
        version="2.5">
      <display-name>spring-tutorial-50</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <description></description>
        <display-name>offers</display-name>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <web:load-on-startup>1</web:load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>offers</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

offers-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-
           3.2.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage.spring.web.controllers">
        </context:component-scan>
        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <bean id="jspViewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsps/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

Controller:

```
    @Controller
    public class OffersController {

        private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OffersController.class);

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String showHome(){

            log.info("showHome() called"); 
            return "home";

        }
    }
```

home.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Inside jsps</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Hi Mom!
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to Spring 3.2.17 for all of my Maven library references. When I cleaned and redeployed It worked! @RequestMethod("/") by itself will work if the server is configured properly. It is also possible to get more explicit on what a RequestMethod can handle with things like the following: @RequestMethod(value="/spring", method = RequestMethod.GET) as @javaguy lists. value = "/" etc. also works.

Answer (score 0):

You did NOT map `/spring` URI to the controller `RequestMapping`, look at the below code for the correct mapping:

```
@Controller
    public class OffersController {

        private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(OffersController.class);

        //Map RequestMapping to /spring
        @RequestMapping("/spring", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showHome(){

            log.info("showHome() called"); 
            return "home";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried "/spring" in the Controller @RequestMapping().  It does not work.  The original warning remains.  From what I've read from other posts / should service all requests.  I've already tried variations of /spring and /spring/ to no avail.

Comment: Added method=RequestMethod.GET to the @RequestMapping, try it